# Does Kaa have messaging mechanism to external systems?

Tags: kaa

Is there any option in Kaa when device contacted the Kaa platform with some data, Is it able to send the same information to our external systems through message broker? For example when a temperature sensor updated the current temperature value to the Kaa, Is kaa able to send the same information to the Messaging brokers like ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the Kafka or Flume appender of Kaa.

I try to use the Kafka appender to send the data from some sensor to storm server like below reference and it works fine.
https://www.kaaproject.org/iot-real-time-data-processing-in-storm-using-kaa/

And you also can custom your appender by following below url:
https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Customization-guide/Log-appenders/

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to do that which are better or not depending on your particular use case.

But, usually the most efficient way would be to use one of the existing [Log Appenders](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/#existing-log-appender-implementations) that are running on the Kaa server side and were specifically created for such messaging.